# Completion handler with nil value

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create a function with completion handler and I would like to make the handler so I can pass in nil.

```
func animate(completion: @escaping((Bool) -> ()) {
  //Do stuff
  completion(true)
}
```

I would like make the make the completion handler to be able to pass in nil when it's not needed, like:

```
animate(completion: nil)
```

It's not working & I get the error:

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '(Bool?) -> ()

. Can you please help me how to do this?

Comment: closure in function arguments  swift can be treated as any other argument type and hence can be made optional.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `@escaping` keyword and make closure optional by specifying default value. Note that this way optional closure de-facto remains escaping.

```
func animate(_ completion: ((Bool) -> ())? = nil) {
    //Do stuff
    completion?(true)
}
```

**Possible usages:**

```
animate({ value in
    print("Completion value: \(value)")
})
animate(nil)
animate() // pass nothing, because default value is nil
```

As trailing closure:

```
animate() { value in
    print("Completion value: \(value)")
}
```